# Storing item currencies in SQLite database

Tags: sqlite, database-design

I'm building out a schema for a site that will need to store a product's currency. I'm not sure whether I'll be needing to be able to convert from one currency to another, however, I'm presuming that will probably be necessary. My db schema is below. (this is for a mobile app btw). My question is, should I just simplify things by adding an additional column called *currency* to my item table? Does my design make sense? Thank you.

**Edit** (based on reply from *Victor* below): the items have a many-to-many relationship with order table. How about putting the currency id on order table since most likely all items in an order will be in the same currency?

**exchange_rates**

1. id
2. currency_from
3. currency_to
4. ex_rate

**item_currencies**

1. currency_id
2. item_id (from items/products table)

**currencies**

1. id
2. code
3. symbol

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The schema looks good but I think that the *item_currencies* table is not necessary.

In your `items` table you can just add the currency_id column. Keep it together with all the item properties :)

Comment: Thanks. that makes sense. the items have a many-to-many relationship with *order* table. How about putting the currency id on *order* table since most likely all items in an order will be in the same currency?

Comment: For sure, you got the idea ;)